# Gradle signingConfigs with multiple keys for same APK

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to set up Gradle to sign the same APK with 2 different keys?

something like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("key1.jks")
        storePassword "password1"
        keyAlias "my-alias1"
        keyPassword "password1"

        storeFile file("key2.jks")
        storePassword "password2"
        keyAlias "my-alias2"
        keyPassword "password2"
    }
}
```

(the above example will actually sign it with *only* key #2, *skipping* key1)

I know I can do it through command line:

> apksigner sign --ks keyname1.jks --ks-pass stdin --key-pass stdin
>   --next-signer --ks keyname2.jks --ks-pass stdin --key-pass stdin --out app-release.apk unsigned.apk

This will create 1 apk that's signed with 2 different keys

Comment: the keys can be different for different flavours say release and debug.

Comment: I know about different flavors, but how about one flavor with 2 keys?

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can do it through command line:
>
> apksigner sign --ks keyname1.jks --ks-pass stdin --key-pass stdin
>   --next-signer --ks keyname2.jks --ks-pass stdin --key-pass stdin --out app-release.apk unsigned.apk

Gradle is using concept of `task` to have job done, so you can simply create own task to the build and sign your way.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html